# Firing a Coil on Plug

Tags: sparkplugs, diagnostics

I was wondering if there is a simple way of firing a coil on plug outside of the car. The coil in question is just a two wire coil on plug and I don't know if its possible to just hook up a 12V voltage source to it to see if it will fire. Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would follow these simple steps.

1. Remove plug from engine
2. Place plug into coil wire
3. Make sure threads of the sparkplug are grounded to a metal surface.
4. Validate metal surface goes to ground by using a multimeter

Here is some multimeter basics for you.

[Multimeter - Basic Functionality and Howto](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25816/multimeter-basic-functionality-and-howto/25884#25884)

5. Once the sparkplug is grounded to the chassis of the car you can turn it over and look at the sparkplug to see if you have spark.

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

If it is a coil that connects directly to a spark plug, then I believe that they need a higher voltage than 12v pulsed into them.  They are not the same as the old fashioned large coils that were found on engines with points, where a large current at 12v was used to fire them.