# My Yamaha cut off while idling and now there is no power

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, ignition, yamaha, fzr600

I Started my FZR600 this morning for work. Normal crank. As I lowered the choke it started to die out so I tried to give it some throttle but it didn't help. The bike cut off completely. Checked all the fuses and they are fine, but NOTHING turns on when I turn the key to on.

No gauges, lights, nothing. causes?

Comment: What year is the bike?

Comment: no lights or gauges? I'd suggest flat battery. The cause of that could be bad alternator, short, bad battery...

Comment: Seems weird that it would start and run and after it dies there are no lights and what not.  Seems more like a main fuse or something.

Comment: Worth rechecking the fuses then Shanna

Comment: Shanna If you can provide the year I can tell you where the main fuse is.

Comment: Just a note, if the main fuse isn't blown, and the battery is dead, your alternator/rectifier is stuffed too. A good alternator/regulator pair will keep the bike running once started. Had that happen to me late last year, alternator was toast, brand new battery went flat on the highway, bike totally dead electrically.

Comment: would love to try and answer your question if you could provide the model year of the bike.

Answer (score 4):

I would suspect one of two things.

1. **Your main fuse is blown.**  This would disable your entire electrical system and prevent the bike from lighting up or starting.
2. **Your ignition switch has failed.**  If your ignition switch where you turn your key has failed your electrical system will be dark.

If you have a multimeter you can unplug your ignition switch from the wiring harness.  At the connector for the ignition switch you can check for continuity at the plug.  Check between your power and ground, if you have infinite resistance on your multimeter then the contacts for providing the power could be bad and an ignition switch replacement is needed.

You can pull your main fuse and inspect visually as well as test it for continuity when it's out of the bike.  I have seen fuses that look fine and fail this test before.

Here is a multimeter usage and howto link

[Multimeter - Basic Functionality and Howto](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25816/multimeter-basic-functionality-and-howto)

Hope this is helpful.